# JavaScript Event Listener runs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

As reference, please see my example in JSFiddle below. Every time somebody clicks on the plus button, a new row should be inserted below. This works fine except the fact that the amount of new rows inserted is always twice the amount of current existing rows. How can I avoid this strange behavior, or what's the reason for it? Please click the first rows button to see the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jrxeua6L/

```
var answers = [{
    order: 1,
    content: "placeholder"
}],
    appendAnswer = function() {

    answers.push({
        order: answers.length + 1,
        content: $(this).parent().prev().val()
    });

    $("#answers").empty();

    $.each(answers, function(key, value) {
        $("#answers").append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your answer"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add a question" data-action="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Delete this question" data-action="delete" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></span></div>');

        $("#answers button[data-action='add']").one("click", appendAnswer);
    });
};

$("#answers button[data-action='add']").one("click", appendAnswer);
```

Comment: You're appending to each of the `answers` instead of appending to the answer container.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `one` instead of `on`?

Comment: Yeah, I used .one() because I thought this would solve the issue. Before this, I used .on(). But problem is solved, anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event-delegation

```
$("#answers").on("click", "button[data-action='add']",appendAnswer);
```

The cause of your problem is that you are binding multiple events on same elements in the each loop, so remove the delegation there.

Remove this line below from the `.each()` loop

```
$("#answers button[data-action='add']").one("click", appendAnswer);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrxeua6L/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But I don't understand how, because I always thought that if I append a element dynamically to the DOM, the event listener must be reattached.
EDIT: Ah, I see. Now I understand your solution and it makes sense. Thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/jrxeua6L/4/

```
var answers = [{
            order: 1,
            content: "placeholder"
        }],
            appendAnswer = function() {

            answers.push({
                order: answers.length + 1,
                content: $(this).parent().prev().val()
            });

            $("#answers").empty();

            $.each(answers, function(key, value) {
                $("#answers").append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your answer"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add a question" data-action="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Delete this question" data-action="delete" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></span></div>');

                //$("#answers button[data-action='add']").on("click", appendAnswer);
            });
        };

        $('body').on("click", "#answers button[data-action='add']", appendAnswer);
```

Comment: Don't know, it's the same solution as Anton provided. It also works fine, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
$("#answers button[data-action='add']").one("click", appendAnswer);
```

To this:

```
$("#answers button[data-action='add']").off("click").one("click", appendAnswer);
```